# How do I click this XPath button with Selenium for Python?

Tags: selenium

The `XPath` is:

```
//*[@id="pricing_table_1"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[3]
```

But it doesn't work on click using:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pricing_table_1"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[3]').click()
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the pertinent section of the markup you're working with?

Comment: Post the html and explain what happened when you tried it.

Comment: The html is too long to post,  but it's all on https://offerwall.minutecircuit.com/display.php?app_id=1181&site_code=177b6dfaa59a4908&user_id=76561198831569338&site_type=all .

Answer (score 0):

The element you are trying to find is inside another frame, so first you need to switch to that frame and then search the element.

Try this:

```
browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pricing_table_1"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[3]').click()
```